# How to use setInterval and clearInterval to move text diagonally left (back to start) after moving right and down

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the result of what I am trying to accomplish using only JavaScript (no jQuery or CSS) with setInterval and clearInterval:

[image: Result]

I have to begin moving the text from the top-left corner to the top-right corner of a window's browser. When it reaches the top-right corner, the text will begin to move down to the bottom-right corner. After that, it will go back to its start position and stop. I am able to move the text to the right and bottom, but not back to the start position. I have tried various ways to wrap my head around this one part and have been unsuccessful. Any help would be much appreciated. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisLeft=0;
var thisTop=0;
var moveID=0;

var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

// Function to move the text
function moveText(){
 
 var thisText= document.getElementById('myDiv');
 if (thisLeft < width ){
  thisLeft += 100; //how much the text moves right
 }else if (thisLeft >= width) {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "blue";
  document.getElementById("myDiv").style.fontSize= "xx-Large";
  document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML= "moveDown";
  thisTop +=100; //how much the text moves down
 }
 
 if (thisTop >= height && thisLeft >= width){
  thisTop -= 100;
  thisLeft -= 100;
 }


 thisText.style.left=thisLeft +"px";
 thisText.style.top=thisTop +"px";
 }

// how long it will take the text move to complete
function doMove(){
moveID=setInterval(moveText, 500);
}

</script>
</head>
<body  onload= "doMove()" >
<div id="myDiv"style="position:absolute;" >
<p>movingRight</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: to correct for scaling you can do http://jsbin.com/hahufocoxa/1/edit?html,output.  I have also stopped the timer

Comment: Oh, I see. I was multiplying the ratio in the wrong spot, particularly one of the global variables I declared for the window width and height. Again, I really appreciate all of your help on this and thank you for introducing new concepts to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a state based approach and move to another state after every change of direction.

One thing you'd also need to do, that I haven't included in my code below, is to scale either `thisLeft` or `thisTop` by the ratio of width to height to get back to the start due to the page not being square.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var thisLeft=0;
var thisTop=0;
var moveID=0;

var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
var height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

var state = 1;

// Function to move the text
function moveText(){

    var thisText= document.getElementById('myDiv');

    if (state == 1){
        thisLeft += 100; //how much the text moves right

    } else if (state == 2) {
        thisTop +=100; //how much the text moves down

    } else if (state == 3) {
        thisTop -= 100;
        thisLeft -= 100;
    }

    if (state == 1 && thisLeft >= width ){
        state = 2;
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color = "blue";
        document.getElementById("myDiv").style.fontSize= "xx-Large";
        document.getElementById('myDiv').innerHTML= "moveDown";
    } else if (state == 2 && (thisTop >= height)) {
        state = 3;
    } else if (state == 3 && (thisLeft <= 0)) {
        state = 0;
    }

    thisText.style.left=thisLeft +"px";
    thisText.style.top=thisTop +"px";
}

// how long it will take the text move to complete
function doMove(){
moveID=setInterval(moveText, 500);
}

</script>
</head>
<body  onload= "doMove()" >
<div id="myDiv"style="position:absolute;" >
<p>movingRight</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/latotujuga/edit?html,output

Comment: Is there any documentation on state? I've never come across it before and I'd like to understand the code a bit more, granted I just started learning JavaScript.

Comment: I've created a basic Finite State Machine (FSM). It's not something specific to the language, just a way of approaching a problem - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: In your case each 'state' is a particular direction you want to travel in for some period. The system stays in that state until it meets a condition (eg. > width) and then it moves to the next state. It then stays in that state while checking against a new condition (> height) and then moves to the next. That just repeats until done. If you want to loop set it back to `state = 1` instead of `state = 0`

Comment: Ah, okay, I think it's making sense to me now. I didn't know something like that was even possible! This project was driving me nuts the past few days. Thank you so much for your help! Is this approach applicable in other scripting languages?

Comment: Yes it is applicable to other languages

Comment: I hate to ask again for more help, but I was looking into your other suggestion about scaling and came across a ton of different solutions either using CSS with canvas and various uses of JavaScript. Is there anyway to do this without changing the code too much?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126877/discussion-between-lprox5-and-k-scandrett).